# How to compute euclidean distance between all column vector pairs for a given matrix without using loops? (using only numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance

As titled, I need to calculate the euclidean distance between all possible column vector pairs of a given matrix without using loops and using numpy only.

This produces the output I'm looking for (but with loops):

```
import numpy as np
def all_column_euclidean(x):
    output = np.zeros((len(x[0]),len(x[0])))
    for i in range(len(x[0])):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
                   output[i][j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])**2))
    return output
```

Comment: I don't know if that is even possible. Since you are guaranteed to have more than one point involved, you're going to use a for loop, implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Feed transpose of the input to the proposed answers in the linked Q&A and then get squared-root.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions for that in `scipy.spatial.distance`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist,squareform

a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,4))

# pairwise dist, compressed
pdist(a.T)
# array([ 8.60232527,  8.77496439, 10.29563014,  6.70820393,  8.1240384 ,
#         3.        ])

# same expanded to full table
squareform(pdist(a.T))
# array([[ 0.        ,  8.60232527,  8.77496439, 10.29563014],
#        [ 8.60232527,  0.        ,  6.70820393,  8.1240384 ],
#        [ 8.77496439,  6.70820393,  0.        ,  3.        ],
#        [10.29563014,  8.1240384 ,  3.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with only Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy's broadcast feature to do that which will be faster than python loop

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

# calculate xi-xj for all i,j pair
xi_minus_xj = x - x.reshape(-1,1)

# calculate yi-yj for all i,j pair
yi_minus_yj = y - y.reshape(-1,1)

# calculate (xi-xj)**2 + (yi-yj)**2 for all i, j pair
distances = np.sqrt(xi_minus_xj**2 + yi_minus_yj**2)


# get distance between ith and jth item
print(distances[2,3])
print(distances[2,2])
print(distances[1,8])
```

**Edit**
It will be even simpler if you have points as array of (x,y) as below

```py
import numpy as np
points = np.arange(20).reshape(-1,2)
print(points)

## calculate xi-xj and yi-yj for all pairs
diff = points - points[:,np.newaxis,:]

## calculate sqrt((xi-xj)**2 + (yi-yj)**2 )for all pairs
distances = np.sqrt(np.sum(diff**2,axis=2))


## get distance between ith and jth points
print(distances[2,5])
print(distances[5,5])
print(distances[8,5])
```

Comment: How would you go about extracting the columns from a single matrix to do that broadcasting?

Comment: what is size of your matrix? you can use broadcasting on matrix itself without extracting column

Comment: @JoeAverage I have edited my answer for list of points instead of separate  array of x and y

Answer (score 0):

S.Vengat is right, you will have to use loops one way or another, however there is a 
library which can help you do this in 1 line:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(data.T,data.T)
```

which gives:

```
array([[0.        , 1.73205081, 3.46410162],
       [1.73205081, 0.        , 1.73205081],
       [3.46410162, 1.73205081, 0.        ]])
```

Your code for comparision:

```
import numpy as np
def all_column_euclidean(x):
    output = np.zeros((len(x[0]),len(x[0])))
    for i in range(len(x[0])):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
                   output[i][j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((x[:,i]-x[:,j])**2))
    return output    
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(all_column_euclidean(data))
```

Output:

```
[[0.         1.73205081 3.46410162]
 [1.73205081 0.         1.73205081]
 [3.46410162 1.73205081 0.        ]]
```